# how to secure Kong Admin Api?

Tags: docker, security, api, api-gateway

I'm setting up the Kong gateway manager locally using Docker.
the requests will be sent to localhost:8000, and admin will be available in localhost:8002.

How can I secure these ports locally when deployed in Docker?

I want to deploy it in the Kubernetes cluster. How do I do the same?

FYI: I'm using Kong open source.